# How do I add the DataGridView component to Visual Studio Community and my project

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, visual-studio-community

I want to use the `DataGridView` in my `WPF` project.  I see it in my toolbox list but it is inactive.  I cannot figure out how to activate it and make available to my project.

Comment: #Karolis -- But it is not availabsle for me to place inside a DataGrid.  It is greyed out in my toolbox.  Also in the xml when I type <datagridview it is not there for me to choose.

Comment: DataGridView only exists in WinForms and you must have a toolbox for it as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I see it in my toolbox list but it is inactive.

[`DataGridView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0ywh3cz(v=vs.110).aspx) is a windows forms control and can not be used in a WPF window directly. 
For a WPF project you need to use [`DataGrid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) control.

You should right click on toolbox and uncheck *Show All*, this way you will see just those components which are available for the current open designer.

Comment: Thank you all. I was confused on how it worked. Whenever I do a google search it always brings up datagridview and someone had says said datagridview was the replacement for daragrid.

Comment: The `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView` is a replacement for `System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid` which is different from `System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid`.